# Sum of the selected items of a pages drop down menus

Tags: javascript, html

My page has a table which has a series of drop down menus in one column (all of which contain a series of numbers), I want to run a function every time one of the values is changed, that takes the sum of the values and displays the result on the page. I believe my function (totalMarks), gets a collection of all my drop down menus, then loops through them, adding to the total the value of the selected index, and then displaying the total marks within a some h2 tags. Is my problem within the summing of the drop down menus or somewhere else?

```
function markForm(tagID) {
    var x = document.getElementById(tagID)
    var pre = document.createElement("pre");
    x.appendChild(pre);
    var SectionDetails = [
        { name: "Dynamic Table", maxMarks: 20},
        { name: "IntelliJ usage", maxMarks: 10},
        { name: "Calendar Controller", maxMarks: 30},
        { name: "Active Form", maxMarks: 20},
        { name: "Object Database", maxMarks: 20}
    ];
    var table = pre.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
    var tableHeader = table.appendChild(document.createElement("thead"));
    var tableRow = tableHeader.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
    var headRow = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement("th"));
    headRow.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Section"));
    headRow = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement("th"));
    headRow.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Max Mark"));
    headRow = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement("th"));
    headRow.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Comments"));
    headRow = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement("th"));
    headRow.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Mark"));
    var resultsRows = table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
    for (var i = 0; i < SectionDetails.length; i++) {
        tableRow = resultsRows.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
        var tableData = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
        tableData.appendChild(document.createTextNode(SectionDetails[i].name));
        tableData = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
        tableData.appendChild(document.createTextNode(SectionDetails[i].maxMarks));
        tableData = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
        var tarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        tarea.value = "Enter Comments";
        tableData.appendChild(tarea);
        tableData = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
        var dropDown = document.createElement("select");
        dropDown.name = SectionDetails[i].name;
        dropDown.setAttribute("onchange", totalMarks());
        for (var j = 0; j < (SectionDetails[i].maxMarks + 1); j++) {
            var listItem = new Option(j);
            listItem.value=j;
            dropDown.appendChild(listItem);
        }
        tableData.appendChild(dropDown);
    }
    var h2 = document.createElement("h2");
    h2.id = "headline";
    h2.innerHTML = "Total Marks: 0";
    x.appendChild(h2);
}

function totalMarks() {
    var total = 0;
    var ddmenus = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var a = 0; a < ddmenus.length; a++) {
        total = total + ddmenus[a].options[ddmenus[a].selectedIndex].value;
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("h2").innerHTML = "Total Marks: " + total;
}
```

[image]

How the page should look, and does if I don't include the line "document.getElementById("marksline").innerHTML = "Total Marks: " + total;"

[image]

How the page looks if I leave the above mentioned line in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two things to take care of:

1. parseInt the value of selected option

   ```
   total = total + parseInt(ddmenus[a].options[ddmenus[a].selectedIndex].value);
   ```
2. Give the h2 an id (e.g. 'headline') and assign the value with getElementById

   ```
   document.getElementById("headline").innerHTML = "Total Marks: " + total;
   ```

Edit: for clarification. If you `getElementsByTagName` you get an array of elements. For assigning a value you need to choose one out of the array e.g. `document.getElementByTagName('h2')[0]` would be the first h2 on the page.

Comment: Thanks makes sense, but for some reason, when I add that final line to display the total, my loop creating my table seems to stop working when it reaches the creation of the first drop down menu, I'll add some screenshots in the op. Any ideas?

Comment: You should at the end only have one h2 with id="headline", otherwise it will break. Is there a chance you try to create more than one h2 with that id?
Maybe a bit more of your code helps understand what you are doing. Or look at console for errors.

Comment: I only have the one h2 in the document so I don't think it's that, could it be that I'm creating the drop down menus and calling the function onchange so it's running straight away before the h2 element is created? I've added the full code to the op now. Ok the console says what I mentioned is the error, easiest way to work around that?

Comment: Just create the h2 first. You can put in the table before that later with insertBefore() function.

Comment: Forget about the last comment. The error is that you assign the onchange function incorrect. It needs to be a string,

        dropDown.setAttribute("onchange", 'totalMarks()');

Comment: ah I see, still getting used to Javascript so thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: No worries, just keep a close look at your console ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `parse` value of dropdown in `integer` as `value` is a `string` by default.

```
total = total + parseInt(ddmenus[a].options[ddmenus[a].selectedIndex].value);
```